# Mongoose Object to CSV in Rendered EJS view

Tags: csv, express, mongoose, ejs

I currently have an application which renders an EJS page and displays mongoose query results. The data is sent to the template page as **queryResults**. Once it has displayed these results, I am trying to add a button at the bottom that allows to export **queryResults** to a CSV file. While there are many npm packages that convert data, I am unsure how to approach this. The data is display on the rendered page using the following code:

```
<div class="resultsBox"> 
    <% queryResults.forEach(function(results){ %>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
      <a id="jobRefLink" href="/search/<%= results._id %>">
      <%=results.jobTicket %></a></div>
...
...
...
       </div>
    <% }); %>

<a href="#">Export</a>
```

I have tried installing various pages but they all seem to work server-side and while this is not a problem, I am unsure how to implement these on the client side and getting that data back to an appropriate route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv#json2csv-transform-streaming-api) package to generate CSV.

The code example

```
const Json2csvParser = require('json2csv').Parser;
  //const fields = ['car', 'price', 'color'];
  const fields = [{
                      "label": 'Car Name',
                      "value": 'car'
                    },{
                      "label": 'Price USD',
                      "value": 'price'
                    },{
                      "label": 'color Color',
                      "value": 'color'
                    }
                    ];

  const myCars = [
    {
      "car": "Audi",
      "price": 40000,
      "color": "blue"
    }, {
      "car": "BMW",
      "price": 35000,
      "color": "black"
    }, {
      "car": "Porsche",
      "price": 60000,
      "color ff": "green"
    }
  ];

  const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ fields });
  const csv = json2csvParser.parse(myCars);

  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/csv");
  res.setHeader("Content-Length" , csv.length);
  res.setHeader("Content-type" ,"text/x-txt; charset=utf-8");
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=surveyresponse.csv");
  res.render('export', { listData: csv });;
```

The res header will generate csv. and on export.ejs file just write only

```
<%- listData %> then it will download as a csv.
```

Comment: The data has already been rendered to the page. How would I then use this to then export to csv?

Comment: I edit last line of code res.render('export', { listData: csv }); make a export.ejs file then it will download as a csv file